# var/www won't work

Tags: apache2, php, lamp

I've installed the LAMP stack on my Ubuntu 14.04 laptop using the command:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

I went to localhost and it shows the typical tree (Index of ... https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPc8A.png in my case the tree is empty).

So I type at the command line `sudo service apache2 start`

After that I create a hello world php file, called **example.php**

And then I put that file inside **var/www folder** (to getto that folder I go to files and then to system, and then to var folder, and then to www folder).

And finally I open my browser and type **localhost/example.php**

**The file appears as not found.**

Note: From the console I've done this also: `sudo chmod -R 755 var/www` 
I've also checked www folder perms and anybody has access files and I have "create and delete files" permission.

What should I do? The files are there but localhost show an empty list and Any file is "not found" when I try to acess it from the browser.

Comment: Aside from the DocumentRoot issue, `apt-get install apache2` only installs apache2 surely? To get the full LAMP stack you would need `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^` or equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for linking to that discussion. Haven't read it. But I don't think it's a duplicate because of how the question is set. I mean the result IS the same (the folder is html after all), but I didn't quite realize it, and I thought it was an installation issue.
Anyway, if several people think it's a duplicate, I'll most certainly remove it.

Comment: Thanks @steeldriver haven't realize that! Maybe that's why php wasn't working even after moving the files to the /html folder... :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Ubuntu 14.04 the default `DocumentRoot` is `/var/www/html/` instead of `/var/www/`.

You can change this in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` (but is usually better to keep it it like this).

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know that (why they would do that, anyway?). The folder wasn't accessible, so I've: sudo chown 'myusername.users /var/www/html'